# Restore data from back up

Tags: plsql

Im trying to restore data from dump file into a table without duplicate values. For which im putting the data from dump file into a temporary table. Now i need to compare the contents of temporary table and existing table.After which Whatever rows are not present in original table should be added to it from temporary table.

```
declare
table_name varchar(30);
poid_id0 au_account_t.poid_id0%type;
CURSOR row_pointer  is
SELECT MIN(au_account_t) as table_name,POID_ID0
FROM
(
SELECT 'au_account_t' as au_account_t, au_account_t.POID_ID0
FROM au_account_t
UNION ALL
SELECT 'au_account_t_temp' as au_account_t_temp, au_account_t_temp.POID_ID0
FROM au_account_t_temp
) tmp
GROUP BY POID_ID0
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY POID_ID0;
begin
open row_pointer;
loop
fetch row_pointer into table_name,poid_id0;
EXIT WHEN row_pointer%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line(poid_id0);
insert into au_account_t(poid_id0)values (poid_id0); 
end loop;
close row_pointer;
end ;
```

I need to compare all columns not just the primary key poid_id0 and insert the entire row in the main table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multicolumn subquery to do this task, for eg.

```
insert into emp (EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO)
select EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO from temp_emp
where (EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO)
not in (select EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO
 from emp)
```

Comment: insert into au_account_t
select * from au_account_t_temp
where (poid_id0)
not in (select poid_id0
 from au_account_t);
I used this query and it worked ! :) thanks